# How does GridDB handle performance and scalability for large time-series data and compare it to traditional databases?

Tags: griddb

How does the use of GridDB improve performance and scalability when handling large amounts of time series data, such as sensor data from IoT devices, in comparison to traditional relational databases? And how does GridDB handle data consistency and availability in a distributed environment ?